# CAKE throws error claiming argument was not set, even though it was

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, cakebuild

I am using Cake 0.21.1.0.

For my project, as a build step on TeamCity, I execute `build.ps1`, which in turn invokes `build.cake`. I pass in the following arguments to my `build.ps1` script, in accordance with [the CAKE documentation](http://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/args-and-environment-vars):

```
-ScriptArgs '-MSBuildLogger="JetBrains.BuildServer.MSBuildLoggers.MSBuildLogger,%teamcity.dotnet.msbuild.extensions4.0%"'
```

In `build.cake`, I added the following line:

```
var msBuildLogger = Argument<string>("MSBuildLogger");
```

However, the following error was thrown:

```
[15:37:22]Error: Argument 'MSBuildLogger' was not set.
[15:37:22]Process exited with code 1
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What happens if you try: `var msBuildLogger = Argument("MSBuildLogger", "bob");`

Comment: @GaryEwanPark I see the following log:

"[16:03:46]MSBUILD : error MSB1021: Cannot create an instance of the logger. Could not load file or assembly 'bob' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
[16:03:46]Switch: bob
[16:03:46]An error occurred when executing task 'Build'."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following `build.cake` file:

```
var logger = Argument<string>("MSBuildLogger");

Task("Default")
  .Does(() =>
{
  Information(logger);
});

RunTarget("Default");
```

Also, fetch the most recent bootstrapper file from the [resources repository](https://github.com/cake-build/resources) using:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://cakebuild.net/download/bootstrapper/windows -OutFile build.ps1
```

Then run the following:

```
.\build.ps1 -ScriptArgs '-MSBuildLogger="JetBrains.BuildServer.MSBuildLoggers.MSBuildLogger,%teamcity.dotnet.msbuild.extensions4.0%"'
```

Confirm that you are getting the correct output when running the script locally.  i.e. take TeamCity out of the equation.

Comment: I see the same error message when running locally: "Error: Argument 'MSBuildLogger' was not set." I am using Cake 0.21.1.0.

Comment: So, to confirm, using the sample script as shown above (i.e. nothing else), with the exact command shown above, you get that error message?

Comment: It actually works when I explicitly add "MsBuildLogger" as a PowerShell parameter and then pass the argument on to CAKE. But according to the documentation the proper way to do it is to use ``-ScriptArgs``.

Comment: Yes, my ``build.ps1`` script is based on a bootstrapper.

Comment: So you are using a custom bootstrapper?  Or are you using the one from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cake-build/resources/master/build.ps1 The above answer assumed you were using the default bootstrapper.

Comment: I am using the ``build.ps1`` template from here: https://github.com/marcosnz/Cake-Example

Comment: Ah, I see. That sample is almost 2 years old. I would suggest using the up-to-date bootstrapper from the resources repository. This is the file that you would get if you ran the command in the Getting Started section here: https://www.cakebuild.net/docs/tutorials/setting-up-a-new-project

Comment: This ended my morning of pain trying to get better output from MSBuild to TeamCity (instead of it all just being buried in the build log). I had to make a slight change though as that argument didn't work verbatim for me. I needed just the dll path: `--tcLogger="%teamcity.dotnet.msbuild.extensions4.0%"`

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth have you seen/used the Cake.BuildSystems.Module? I provides some enhancements to things like logging in TeamCity: https://blog.agchapman.com/introducing-the-cake-build-systems-module/

Comment: @GaryEwanPark I had stumbled across it a handful of times but couldn't find anything comprehensive about it. I will read your blog and look at tech spiking it.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark Actually I've read that post before. If I add the tools/modules/packages.config what is the package for TeamCity? Or do I just need to have the `cake` package in there?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Not sure I follow your question, sorry.  Perhaps start a new question with some more details and we can continue discussion there, as I don't think this is related to this question.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark It's alright, got it working. build.ps1 was deleting the modules folder if it was the only thing around (we don't commit `tools` to source, but I had to make the exception for tools/modules/packages.config). After I did that, it all worked as expected.